# Sending data between 2 classes with Delegate Methods

Tags: swift, photo, multipeer-connectivity

I am trying to send data between 2 classes via **MultipeerConnectivity**. I am trying to do this via delegate methods.

I have defined this protocol:

```
protocol AssetDelegate {
    func changeThisName(data: Data)
}
```

My main ViewController is the **AssetDelegate** and has implemented the function simply as:

```
func changeThisName(data: Data) {
    print("changeThisName called")
    if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
        imageViewAsset.image = image
    }
}
```

This is simply to see if a received image can be decoded and assigned to the imageViewAsset UI element.

This method is called within a MultipeerConnectivity "Manager" class that I have defined, which has an instance in the AppDelegate (is this the definition of a "singleton"?)

My "MPCManager" class has the various MCSession delegate methods, specifically session(didReceive:data) method, which is:

```
var assetDelegate: AssetDelegate?

func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive data: Data, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
    print("Data Recieved: \(data)")
    self.assetDelegate?.changeThisName(data: data)
}
```

I see the `print("Data Received:(data)")` in the console log. But I do not see the print statement of the changeThisName method.

This is the console log output. Essentially there are 2 rows showing the MPC connectivity ("other state" and "session connected"). Then there are 2 "Received Data" items.

```
2019-08-14 12:42:29.714402+0100 My App[34860:11895498] [Accessibility] ****************** Loading GAX Client Bundle ****************
2019-08-14 12:42:44.121481+0100 My App[34860:11895563]  [ERROR] ICEStopConnectivityCheck:2688 ICEStopConnectivityCheck() found no ICE check with call id (1193667819)
other state...<MCPeerID: 0x281b541c0 DisplayName = SendDevice>
2019-08-14 12:42:45.493567+0100 My App[34860:11895661]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199   Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0041).
2019-08-14 12:42:45.542647+0100 My App[34860:11895661]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199   Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0041).
2019-08-14 12:42:45.586389+0100 My App[34860:11895661]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199   Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0041).
2019-08-14 12:42:45.641138+0100 My App[34860:11895661]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199   Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0041).
2019-08-14 12:42:45.730210+0100 My App[34860:11895661]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199   Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0041).
2019-08-14 12:42:45.795905+0100 My App[34860:11895661]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199   Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0041).
2019-08-14 12:42:45.968786+0100 My App[34860:11895661]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199   Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0041).
session connected... <MCPeerID: 0x281b541c0 DisplayName = SendDevice>
2019-08-14 12:42:46.037399+0100 My App[34860:11895661]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199   Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0041).
2019-08-14 12:42:46.379153+0100 My App[34860:11895661]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199   Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0041).
2019-08-14 12:42:46.444389+0100 My App[34860:11895661]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199   Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0041).
2019-08-14 12:42:47.099950+0100 My App[34860:11895661]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199   Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0041).
2019-08-14 12:42:47.158868+0100 My App[34860:11895661]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199   Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0041).
2019-08-14 12:42:48.351072+0100 My App[34860:11895661]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199   Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0041).
2019-08-14 12:42:48.390215+0100 My App[34860:11895661]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199   Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0041).
2019-08-14 12:42:49.856339+0100 My App[34860:11895661]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199   Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0041).
2019-08-14 12:42:49.922462+0100 My App[34860:11895661]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199   Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0041).
Data Recieved: 8269 bytes
2019-08-14 12:42:51.375239+0100 My App[34860:11895661]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199   Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0041).
2019-08-14 12:42:51.454734+0100 My App[34860:11895661]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199   Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0041).
2019-08-14 12:42:52.913337+0100 My App[34860:11895661]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199   Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0041).
2019-08-14 12:42:52.977319+0100 My App[34860:11895661]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1199   Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(C01A0041).
Data Recieved: 4569624 bytes
2019-08-14 12:42:54.271102+0100 My App[34860:11895531] [GCKSession] Not in connected state, so giving up for participant [4725ECEB] on channel [0].
2019-08-14 12:42:54.293615+0100 My App[34860:11895531] [GCKSession] Not in connected state, so giving up for participant [4725ECEB] on channel [1].
2019-08-14 12:42:54.306191+0100 My App[34860:11895531]  [ERROR] ICEStopConnectivityCheck:2688 ICEStopConnectivityCheck() found no ICE check with call id (1193667819)
2019-08-14 12:42:54.306387+0100 My App[34860:11895531] [GCKSession] Not in connected state, so giving up for participant [4725ECEB] on channel [2].
2019-08-14 12:42:54.313382+0100 My App[34860:11895531]  [ERROR] ICEStopConnectivityCheck:2688 ICEStopConnectivityCheck() found no ICE check with call id (1193667819)
2019-08-14 12:42:54.313444+0100 My App[34860:11895531] [GCKSession] Not in connected state, so giving up for participant [4725ECEB] on channel [3].
2019-08-14 12:42:54.318396+0100 My App[34860:11895531]  [ERROR] ICEStopConnectivityCheck:2688 ICEStopConnectivityCheck() found no ICE check with call id (1193667819)
2019-08-14 12:42:54.318453+0100 My App[34860:11895531] [GCKSession] Not in connected state, so giving up for participant [4725ECEB] on channel [5].
2019-08-14 12:42:54.323359+0100 My App[34860:11895531]  [ERROR] ICEStopConnectivityCheck:2688 ICEStopConnectivityCheck() found no ICE check with call id (1193667819)
2019-08-14 12:42:54.323407+0100 My App[34860:11895531] [GCKSession] Not in connected state, so giving up for participant [4725ECEB] on channel [6].
2019-08-14 12:42:54.328377+0100 My App[34860:11895531]  [ERROR] ICEStopConnectivityCheck:2688 ICEStopConnectivityCheck() found no ICE check with call id (1193667819)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protocol AssetDelegate {
    func changeThisName(data: Data)
}

class A: AssetDelegate {
    func goToClassB(){
        var b = B()
        b.assetDelegate = self // <-- I don't see this line in your code
    }
}

class B {
    var assetDelegate: AssetDelegate?

    func passDataToA(){
        self.assetDelegate?.changeThisName(whatEverDataHere)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. I am getting confused with which class needs to contain which code.... In your example, "Class A" is where the data is being sent to (receiver)? In my case, I think this is my main ViewController class, which also contains the IBOutlet of my imageView instance. But what type of instance should I have for your equivalent of `var b = B()`? Is it the MPCManager class (managing the Multipeer Connectivity), as this is the class that would make the "send" request / `changeThisName(data)` method call?

Comment: Got basic functionality! The bit throwing me off was creating an instance of "class B". In my case, this was my custom MPCManager class, and my app has an instance that is invoked in AppDelegate (the bit I was wondering if its a "singleton") and already existed... So in my main ViewController's viewDidLoad() function, I have added `appDelegate.mpcManager.assetDelegate = self`, re-ran and now the delegate method is getting called and displaying the images in the imageView as they are received (also had to put this UI update onto the main GCD thread)